# Np.std on 3 dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

`a = (np.arange(12)).reshape(2,2,3)`

I am simply trying to get the standard deviation of each column in my 3D numpy array. When I do this for the mean I get the expected result - each mean in the resulting array is a float.

`a.mean(axis = 0).mean(axis = 0)`

output:

`array([4.5, 5.5, 6.5])`

However, for the standard deviation:

`a.std(axis = 0).std(axis = 0)`

Returns:

`array([0., 0., 0.])`

When verifying that np.std works correctly on one column

`np.std(np.array([1,4,7,10]))`

it returns

`3.3541019662496847`

Why are the column standard deviations returning 0,0,0 ?

Comment: I don't really understand why you would want to take the std of the stds, but it is zero because you get the same standard deviation for all rows when doing `a.std(axis=0)` (from the ways you reshape the array each element in the lowest dimension has std=3). So the std of equal values `a.std(axis=0).std(axis=0)` will be 0.

Comment: Ah okay. All I am trying to do is get the standard deviation of each column

Comment: I see it makes no sense to take it twice, but how do I do this properly?

Comment: I tried to formulate an answer. I think the issue is that you should first reshape to an 2d array, for the solution you are looking for. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 2D-numpy array finding the standard deviation and mean of each column can be done as:

```py
a = (np.arange(12)).reshape(4,3)
a_mean = a.T.mean(axis=1)
a_std = a.T.std(axis=1)
```

As for 3d numpy arrays, I am not sure what exacty you mean with column.
So maybe the solution you are looking for is to first reshape the array into a 2d-numpy array and then use the code above.